# Sending an action to a custom object is crashing the application in ios5.1, xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

If I try to send an action to a custom object, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tested with and without UIStoryboard and with and without ARC. Really strange. The Object seems to be correctly instantiated. -(id)init is called and -(void)awakeFromNib aswell. In the test-xib I added an object and wired it with the custom class. I can wire IBOutlets without any problems. Only actions are crashing. Any ideas?

SimpleObj.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleObj : NSObject
-(IBAction)simpleTest:(id)sender;
@end
```

SimpleObj.h

```
#import "SimpleObj.h"
@implementation SimpleObj
-(IBAction)simpleTest:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
@end
```

Comment: Testing with NSZombieEnabled tells me, that the custom object is already released. So the custom object is instantiated and released immediately... The only way to hold this custom object is by referencing it in the files owner?

Comment: As you have found out yourself, the problem is in the initialization and use of the object, not the IBAction code. You should perhaps post relevant code to have this question answered.

Comment: @fragglechen, right, the local variables will be either released or leaked and the reference will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the custom object is a dangling pointer by the time that the action fires. Top-level objects in a scene are autoreleased, so you must retain them if you'd like to keep 'em around.